# Multiple WebViews with a single loading webview with Visibility == GONE makes another webview unresponsive

Tags: android, android-webview

I am working on an Android browser using WebView(s), and to maintain tabs, multiple webviews are open in a single activity, with 1 always VISIBLE, the rest GONE.

However, when one webview is loading (via .loadUrl()), and then switch to another tab, the 2nd webview with a page already loaded is unresponsive in the sense that I can't click on any links in that until the first webview is loaded.

I can still scroll.

How can I prevent this from happening?

Thanks!